# PsExec slow to start a process

Tags: pstools

PsExec (v2.11) can take up to a minute to invoke a process, either locally or remotely.

I'm using the following command line:

```
psexec.exe -u domain\username -p mypassword -accepteula -d -h \\machinename C:\path\to\myapp.exe
```

I have the firewall disabled on all machines.

What else can I look at?

UPDATE: I used procmon to highlight the delay:

[image]

Comment: It might be your antivirus software checking binary and memory footprint. Try to disable whatever you have to see would it make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The command indirectly open a user session under the specified username to run the process, thus it will be long, you can't do much for that problem.

Only tip to make it a bit faster:

- You can try with -s to run the process as a LOCAL SYSTEM.
- Try with -e, so it does not load the user profile.

Comment: I just tried those, and it doesn't seem to have any effect. It's interesting because this slowness just started today. The IT guys *swear* nothing changed ;-) It used to start rather instantaneously.

Comment: @MarkRichman Check in add/remove program, and verify if any update got installed :) Some nasty (with already know related problem) went live last month.

Comment: Which update has the known issue?

Comment: KB3134228 (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms16-feb.aspx, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3134228) Not wrote in the KB text, but on my side it broke a Citrix PVS's server (5.6SP3) to manage virtual machine active directory password.

Comment: So PsExec is permanently broken by this KB? Or are we waiting for another KB to fix the regression?

Comment: @MarkRichman I just suggest to check if any KB got installed first :) act after :)

Comment: I don't see that particular KB anywhere, and the most recent KB was 5 days ago. Things were working well more recently than that, so that can't be it.

Comment: @MarkRichman anyhow, run a processmonitor and watch where is the timeout would be the next step

Comment: I ran procmon, and you can see the long delay. Otherwise, it's very unrevealing. I've filtered the view to "begins with psexe" to include both psexec and psexesvc. http://imgur.com/2CSknwl

Comment: @MarkRichman in the delay, what is between ? an AV in example ? an dns request to authentificate ? .. please include/analyse it :)

Comment: The procmon trace is huge, so I can't include all the events. But yes, there is McAfee involved. We've disabled it to the extent possible on the machine, but the issue persists. We don't see DNS requests, only LDAP requests to the domain controller for authentication, but those are quick.

Comment: @MarkRichman strangley enought, another user just posted a question about psexec on SF.

Answer (score 0):

On windows server (2008 to 2019) there are 3 default rules that need to be enable:

- Go to: `windows defender firewall with advanced security`
- Go to: `Inbound Rules`
- Right clic on `Inbound Rules` Filter by Group -> `Filter by Remote Service Management`
- Enable those 3 rules for domain (if you set your connection as Domain)

`Remote Service Management (NP-In)` 
 `Remote Service Management (RPC)`  
  `Remote Service Management (RPC-EPMAP)`

PsExec v2.34

C.